# Sum of a function applied to cells

Tags: arrays, openoffice-calc

Is there any way to sum a function applied to a range of cells, without having to use other cells as intermediates?

e.g.

```
=SUM(FLOOR(C2:J2;100))
```

I want to round each of the values c2:j2 down to the nearest multiple of 100, then sum the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just enter the formula as you wrote it, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, this way marking it as **[array formula](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Array_formulas)**. Such formulas are displayed inside curly brackets:

[image: array formula]

Comment: OK, it works, but on a Mac it's Command+Shift+Enter, not Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you're right - i don't have a mac available, so i could test it only on a pc. Glad to hear that it works for you!